# Override where taxonomy menu links (created by Drupal Commerce) point to (new custom taxonomy views instead of default D.C. taxonomy views)

Tags: commerce, taxonomy-terms

I do like how the default Drupal Commerce menu auto-updates with the # of items under that taxonomy like 'Furniture (9)'. 
I'd like to keep that nice feature, but I'd like to change the actual url of those Drupal Commerce main-menu links (point to my Views instead of D.C. default views /products and /product_category/%).

So I manually created 2 new views, one with a conceptional taxonomy filter that looks like /my-products/% and one without the conceptional filter /my-products. They work great.

Now I'd like to repoint the current Taxonomy main-menu to those values ('All Products' would goto my new /my-products 'all products' view, while the rest would goto the new /my-products/% taxonomy-based view based on the taxonomy's term-id).

So how can i do this, is this a template.php override of some sort or GUI based change I can't find yet? I tried here but the Path is hardcoded and not editable:

```
/admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu
```

P.S. using Drupal Commerce Kickstart 2

NOTE: i guess i could remove their menu and just replace with my menu... But I'd lose that ability where D.C. updates the menu text with the # of items in the store, so hence why'd like to keep that :).

Comment: looking at the Drupal Commerce Kickstart Taxonomy module and just other articles, im guessing I have to maybe modify 2 hooks in a new module...
Something like so: 
function  mymodule_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info) {
  $entity_info['taxonomy_term']['uri callback'] = 'mymodule_taxonomy_term_uri';
}
function mymodule_taxonomy_term_uri($taxonomy_term) {   
  return array(
    'path' => 'my-products' . '/' . $taxonomy_term->tid
  );
}
but alas i dont see it ever entering my mymodule_taxonomy_term_uri function (and not sure how 'All Products' is also set). Any ideas?

Comment: getting a bit further. seems like some people are trying to override here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1878088 Posted a comment today asking for help